# How to save/export the emotions detected by a model in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, opencv, face-recognition, face-detection

I have the following code and i want to know if there is a way to save in a dataframe or xlsx every time the program register a emotion?, and if there is a form how should i do it?.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import math
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,1280)
cap.set(4,720)
mpDibujo = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
ConfDibu = mpDibujo.DrawingSpec(thickness = 1, circle_radius = 1)
mpMallaFacial = mp.solutions.face_mesh
MallaFacial = mpMallaFacial.FaceMesh(max_num_faces = 1)
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frameRGB = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    resultados = MallaFacial.process(frameRGB)
    px = []
    py = []
    lista = []
    r = 5
    t = 3
    if resultados.multi_face_landmarks:
        for rostros in resultados.multi_face_landmarks:
            mpDibujo.draw_landmarks(frame, rostros, mpMallaFacial.FACEMESH_TESSELATION, ConfDibu, ConfDibu)
            for id, puntos in enumerate(rostros.landmark):
                al, an, c = frame.shape
                x,y = int(puntos.x*an), int(puntos.y*al)
                px.append(x)
                px.append(y)
                lista.append([id, x, y])
                if len(lista) == 468:
                    x1, y1 = lista[65][1:]
                    x2, y2 = lista[158][1:]
                    cx, cy = (x1 + x2)//2, (y1 + y2)//2
                    longitud1 = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
                    x3, y3 = lista[295][1:]
                    x4, y4 = lista[385][1:]
                    cx2, cy2 = (x3 + x4)//2, (y3 + y4)//2
                    longitud2 = math.hypot(x4 - x3, y4 - y3)
                    x5, y5 = lista[78][1:]
                    x6, y6 = lista[308][1:]
                    cx3, cy3 = (x5 + x6)//2, (y5 + y6)//2
                    longitud3 = math.hypot(x6 - x5, y6 - y5)
                    x7, y7 = lista[13][1:]
                    x8, y8 = lista[14][1:]
                    cx4, cy4 = (x7 + x8)//2, (y7 + y8)//2
                    longitud4 = math.hypot(x8 - x7, y8 - y7)
                    if longitud1 < 19 and longitud2 < 19 and longitud3 > 80 and longitud3 < 95 and longitud4 < 5:
                        cv2.putText(frame, 'Persona enojada', (480,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
                    elif longitud1 > 20 and longitud1 < 30 and longitud2 > 20 and longitud2 < 30 and longitud3 > 109 and longitud4 > 10 and longitud4 < 20:
                        cv2.putText(frame, 'Persona feliz', (480,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 255), 3)
                    elif longitud1 > 35 and longitud2 > 35 and longitud3 > 80 and longitud3 < 90 and longitud4 > 20:
                        cv2.putText(frame, 'Persona asombrada', (480,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
                    elif longitud1 > 20 and longitud1 < 35 and longitud2 > 20 and longitud2 < 35 and longitud3 > 90 and longitud3 < 95 and longitud4 < 5:
                        cv2.putText(frame, 'Persona triste', (480,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
    cv2.imshow("Reconocimiento de emociones", frame)
    t = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if t == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please help and thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that would print to a file object.

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
print('output', output, file=f)  # Python 3.x
print >> f, 'output', output     # Python 2.x
```

there is also a standard library that can do this for you in python 3.4+

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('data')
```

Finally, you can do it externally in console and do this:

```
./script.py > out.txt
```

Comment: It only gives me the word data but nothing more, what else should i put and where?

Comment: Or where i should configure data?

Comment: Where i should configure the 'w' in the code, sorry if i sound too intense

Comment: The 'w' stand for write. Read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp